# How to download and play the song(.mp3,.m4a) if we know the url in android

Tags: android

I need to download a .mp3 or .m4a file from the server by using an URL, and then play that song.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code in your file:

USE

```
url = "your url name+filename.jpg,mp3,etc..."
FileName = "/sdcard/savefilename" // save in your sdcard


  try{
        java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream());
        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(FileName);
        java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int x=0;
        while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
            bout.write(data,0,x);               
        }
        fos.flush();
        bout.flush();
        fos.close();
        bout.close();
        in.close();
  }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     }
```

and after you want to use MediaPlayer
and create object of mediaplayer in your activity
and play.

```
mp.reset();
mp.start();
```

like this.

Hope this will help you a lot.

Comment: @Pintu..it helped me a lot..thanks for ur reply..Everything is fine but it is giving some warnings in Console as                   [2010-12-15 10:11:39 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-12-15 10:11:54 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-12-15 10:11:59 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-12-15 10:18:14 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /): 
[2010-12-15 10:18:19 - ddms]ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /sdcard): .........                                                            ........  can u please tell me what i have to do?

Comment: something wrong with your code or virtual device. Because I am not getting any error from this code. Just check it once.

Comment: this code is nice but how to make this download process run in background??

Answer (score -4):

There are plenty of questions of how to download a file in android. Just search.

On the other hand, you can use android's [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play the file from the internet without downloading it.

Comment: my task is to download the songs from server at starting and then play them locally. If u know how to do it in best way, can please guide me in that way?